# Smallest topology on $\mathbb{C}$ such that all singletons are closed

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

This question was part of an exam for which I am preparing.

> Question was related to finding smallest topology T on $\mathbb{C}$ in which all singletons are closed.
> and then findind which options are true amog these:

A ($\mathbb{C}$,T) is haursdorff.

B ($\mathbb{C}$,T) is compact.

C ($\mathbb{C}$,T) is connected.

D  $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in ($\mathbb{C}$,T) .

But  I am just a beginner in topology and self studying from Wayne patty . I was unable to find what topology should be . So, can you please tell what topology should be . rest I would prefer to work by mysely.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if singletons are closed, are finite sets closed? Is there a topology where only finite sets are closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer the questions A and D, as you asked in the comments.

A is false because if we have two points and any the neighborhoods of them, say $U$ and $V$, they must satisfy $|\mathbb C\setminus U|,|\mathbb C\setminus V|<\infty$ and their intersection, $U \cap V$, is an open subset. If $U\cap V$ is empty, then its complement is union of finite sets, that is $\mathbb C= \mathbb C\setminus (U\cap V)=(\mathbb C \setminus U)\cap (\mathbb C\setminus V)$ is finite, an absurd!

For proving D, we take any non empty, open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb C$, we have $|\mathbb C\setminus U|<\infty$. If $\mathbb Z \cap U =\emptyset$, then $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb C\setminus U$. That is, $\mathbb Z$ is finite, another absurd! So, $\mathbb Z \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Therefore, the integers are dense in $\mathbb C$ with that topology (in fact, any infinite set).

Answer (score 2):

I think the topology you are looking for is the co-finite topology, i.e.

$$ \tau= \{ A\subseteq X: \vert A^c\vert<\infty \} \cup \{ \emptyset\}.  $$

You just have to verify that every topology in which the singletons are closed, contains the co-finite topology, and that the co-finite topology is one of them.

Comment: how you are sure about 1 st line of the answer?

Comment: The justification written later explains it. Minimality means with respect to inclusion, so showing the co-finite topology satisfies the condition and is included in any topology satisfying the condition will be enough.

Comment: Can you please help me proving why  A is false and D is true . I have done others.

Comment: A is false because if we have two points and any the neighborhoods of them, say $U$ and $V$, they satisfy $|\mathbb C\setminus U|, |\mathbb C\setminus V|<\infty$ and  their intersection, $U\cap V$, is an open subset. If $U\cap V$ is empty, then its complement is union of finite sets, that is $\mathbb C=\mathbb C\setminus (U\cap V)= \mathbb C\setminus U \cup \mathbb C\setminus V$ is finite, an absurd!

Comment: For proving D, we take any non empty, open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb C$, we have $|\mathbb C\setminus U| < \infty$. If $\mathbb Z \cap U =\emptyset$, then $\mathbb Z\subseteq \mathbb C\setminus U$. That is, $\mathbb Z$ is finite, another absurd! So, $\mathbb Z\cap U\neq \emptyset$. Therefore, the integers are dense in $\mathbb C$ with that topology (in fact, any infinite set).

Comment: @EmmanuelC. Thank you very much for your help. Both are clear now . Can you please write the 2 comments as asnwer, so that I can accept it?